# Pandas.py is not showing diagram but only AxesSubplot(0.125,0.11;0.775x0.77)

Tags: python, pandas, data-analysis

So i am trying to learn Pandas. In the video which I watch when he types
`dftrain.age.hist(bins=20)` input comes as a diagram but I just don't get any input.
What do you think the problem is?

the whole code is here

```
import pandas as pd

dftrain = pd.read_csv('https://storage.googleapis.com/tf-datasets/titanic/train.csv')
dftrain.age.hist(bins=20)
```

Comment: Remove `print()`

Comment: Are you using Jupyter or running from a command line?  And unless you're running Python 2, the `__future__` line is unnecessary.